# Visual Studio 2012: Why does a type conflict with its own DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am suddenly getting scores of warnings like this:
"The type 'SimShop.SimShopCoilTable' in 'c:\SimShop\SimShopUI\SimShopCoilTable.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'SimShop.SimShopCoilTable' in 'c:\SimShop\SimShopUI\bin\Debug\SimShopUI.dll'. Using the type defined in 'c:\SimShop\SimShopUI\SimShopCoilTable.cs'.

The warnings are all telling me that a type I'm using conflicts with the definition of the type in the DLL that is about to be created!  Why is this happening?

I've been having a hellish time today with the choice between building for Any CPU and for 64-bit processors.  Might it have something to do with that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Time for a Build + Clean.  So you get an error for the apparent problem, having added an inappropriate reference assembly.  You are getting from bad to worse solving this non-existing problem btw.  Maybe time to call it day, Monday will be better :)

Comment: Thanks again for your response.  I am hopelessly confused now, and I'm afraid Monday morning is not going to be better.  What do you mean by "reference assembly"?  I've been doing "Rebuild Solution" all afternoon.  Is that not the same as "Build + Clean"?  I think I may end up just creating a brand new project and loading my existing source code files into it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I made it clear enough:  the assembly in the bin/debug folder is the assembly that is actually being built.  There is not any separate reference to this assembly in my project.